# How do I create a Java Swing component that contains only an image and a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to make a simple component that does nothing other than draw an arbitrary image, and then directly beneath it place a JLabel for displaying arbitrary text.

How can I achieve this? I'm brand new to Swing and I'm trying to learn as I go, but I don't currently understand how I would go about doing this. I know it's a basic question, and I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: If you're new, try to follow a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) before asking questions; and always post code showing what you've tried.

Comment: *"I know it's a basic question.."* See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

JLabel is your friend:

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Your text here");
    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/image/image.jpg")));
```